# How to convert the number 0 with strtol?

Tags: c

I need strtol to convert some numbers from a range of [0 to 255]
how can I check the conversion of 0 if 0 is also a number that i need to convert?

```
long conv = strtol(argv, &p, 10);
if (conv == 0)
{
    perror("Conversion error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if ((conv >= LONG_MAX || conv <= LONG_MIN) && errno == 34);
{
    perror("Invalid Range!");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: Holy crap, that function really does use zero as a signaling value.  Whose idea was that?

Comment: check if p is different from argv

Comment: Actually, I think zero is just the default return value if it cannot parse the string.

Comment: Unknown, [@Ôrel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54009387/how-to-convert-the-number-0-with-strtol#comment94855531_54009387) comments correctly.  After `strtol(argv, &p, 10)`, `if (argv == p)  perror("Conversion error");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prior to calling  `strtol`, set `errno` to 0.

Then after the call, check the value of `errno`.  If it's 0, you know the call was successful.  Addtionally, you'll want to check if `*p` is 0.  If so, that means the entire string was parsed successfully with no extra characters.

```
errno = 0;
long conv = strtol(argv, &p, 10);  
if (errno)
{
    perror("Conversion error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else if (*p)
{
    perror("Not all characters converted");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) also mentions this in the "Notes" section:

> Since strtol() can legitimately return 0, LONG_MAX, or LONG_MIN
>   (LLONG_MAX or LLONG_MIN for strtoll()) on both success and failure,
>   the calling
>          program  should set errno to 0 before the call, and then determine if an error occurred by checking whether errno has a nonzero
>   value after the
>          call.

Comment: I'm not sure it is required that `errno` is set when no conversion is done. The man page says: "The implementation **may** also set errno to EINVAL in case no conversion was performed (no digits seen, and 0 returned)." and the standard only mentions ERANGE as errno in case of over/underflow. This example doesn't set `errno` https://ideone.com/T3ddyH . I think you need to compare `argv` and `p` to catch the case with no conversion

Comment: The C standard has no requirements about `errno` when conversion fails (only range issues). The Linux man page is inconsistent with the C spec on this point.  Code should check `if (argv == p)` for the no conversion condition.

Comment: @chux The code I've posted should account for all error cases, whether or not `errno is set to `EINVAL`.  It both checks `errno` and check that `p` points to the end of the string to test for a complete conversion.

Comment: If `errno` was not set by `strtol()` on a non-conversion (which is compliant with the C standard), this code would errantly not complain about `strtol("", &p, 10);`